# table.ajax is not a function in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

My program is using data-table. Clicking on the button gives an error  "table.ajax is not a function".

Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code snippet

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
var table;
var obj = '1';
$("[id*=btnsubmit]").click(function () {
    obj = $.trim($("[id*=lasttrip]").val());
    reloadDT(obj);
});
function reloadDT() {
    table.ajax({
        url: 'localhost:7001/api/v1/allGetCalls/',
        data: {
            api: 'ts_p_unmatched',
            params: obj
        }
    }).load();
}
```

Comment: It looks like `table` is undefined. You define it at the top of your script, but never assign anything to it.

Comment: Looks like [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax) is an object, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

You defined a variable `table` and after that tried to execute an `.ajax` method on empty variable.

You should run `$.ajax()` not `table.ajax()` to perform a request.